# Diophantine equation - power and multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

In order to see whether I understood the concept of solving Diophantine equations I just thought of an relatively "easy" example of an equation:

Find each $(x,y) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ ( $x,y \neq 0$) such that:

$$ 3x + 1 = 8^y$$

Beforehand - I checked with a program up to $(10000, 10000)$ and the only solution is $(21, 2)$

But when I tried to solve it mathematically - I encountered a dead end.. I hope you will show me the correct path to solve this question.

My try:

So we know that $3x + 1 = (2^3)^y = 2^{3y}$ and thus:

$ 2 \mid 3x+1$  meaning that $x$ needs to be odd - or else this would not be true.

- $2 \nmid x$

Now we can look at the equation $ \text{mod 3}$:

$$ 3x + 1 \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$$

$$ 8^y = (2^{y})^3 \equiv C ( \mod 3)$$
We need to solve for $C$

Through trial and error I got the conclusion that:

$$ 2^1 \equiv 2 ( \mod 3) \\ 2^2 \equiv 1 ( \mod 3)\\ 2^3 \equiv 2 ( \mod 3) \\ \text{etc ..}$$
And so:

$$2^y \equiv 1 ( \mod 3) ~~~ \text{if}  ~~~~ 2 \mid y \\ 2^y \equiv 2 ( \mod 3) ~~~ \text{if}  ~~~~ 2 \nmid y$$

And because the LHS mod $3$ is $1$ :  $y$ must be even.

So we can note: $x = 2k + 1$ and $y = 2l$ ($k,l \in \mathbb{N}$)

Back to the original equation:

$$ 3(2k + 1) + 1 = 8^{2l} \\ 6k + 4 = 2^{6l} $$

Thus $k$ must be even, or else $6k + 4$ will be odd which is impossible as it is equal to a power of $2$.

Continuing where we left off ( dividing by $2$):

$$ 3k + 2 = 2^{6l - 1} \\ 3k = 2^{6l - 1} -2 = 2( 2^{6l-2} - 1)$$

Note we can factor:

$$ 2^{6l -2} - 1  = (2^{3l-1} + 1 )(2^{3l-1} - 1 )$$

Here is where I stopped - I am thinking I am going through loop holes and not really making progress.. I would appreciate if you can lead me into the correct way! Thank you!

Comment: For any even $y$, you have $8^y \equiv 1 (3)$, so for any even $y$ you can write $8^y$ as $8^y=3x+1$ for some integer $x$, i.e. you then have the solution $x=(8^y-1)/3$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis It's a diophantine equation of course I could just write $x$ as you did - the challenge is to get those integer solutions..

Comment: $x$ is an integer when $y$ is even, as you have already proved. Being 1 mod 3 means it is of the form 3x+1 with x integer.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis But the program says there is only 1 solution , not infinite

Comment: The next solution is $y=4$, $x=(8^4-1)/3=4095/3=1365$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis So there are infinite solutions - when $y$ is even: $x = \frac{8^y -1}{3}$ ? How would you write it as a final answer?

Comment: The program must contain a flaw since it missed the solution $(1365/4)$. Since you used search limit $10^4$ , this solution must be detected. Of course, we never can be sure to have found all solutions , if we just apply brute force. And in fact, here are infinite many because for every even $y$ , some $x$ does the job.

Comment: The equation in your last comment is the final answer because for every $y$, we get an integer $x$ with this formula such that the diophantine equation is satisfied. Moreover, there cannot be additional solutions since for odd $y$, $x$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

If we solve for $x$, you get

$$x = \frac{(8^y - 1)}{3}$$

and we find the pairs
$$(0,0)\qquad (21,2)\qquad (1365,4)\qquad (87381,6)\qquad (5592405,8)\qquad (357913941,10)\qquad (22906492245,12)\qquad(1466015503701,14)\qquad (93824992236885,16)\qquad ...$$

I have included zero here but as you can see, any even number $y$ yields an integer for $x$.